# Restore single Gitlab repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to restore a backup from a snapshot for a single repository which I deleted by mistake.

How can I do the same.

P.S: I dont want to restore an entire backup of all the project but a single project.

Regards,
Suvojit

Answer (score 0):

You can try `git-reflog`[link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to see all of your git actions so far. This is some kind of history of your actions. And go to any of those action by `commit sh1`